# How to implement rounded corners for window that call SetWindowCompositionAttribute

Tags: python, qt, winapi, pyqt, acrylic-material

Calling `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` can indeed add the acrylic effect of Win10 to the window, but I have a problem that I still can't solve, that is, how to realize the rounded window while adding the acrylic effect. As shown in the picture below, even if I use `win32guiSetWindowRgn(int(self.winId()),win32gui.CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 500, 500, 500, 500), True)` in pyqt, the acrylic panel cannot be cropped. May I ask Do you have any good ideas?

[image: acrylic window]

Comment: Use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to give the window an alpha channel.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you for your guidance. I checked on the Internet and found that the introduction of this function is very limited. Can you tell me more about how to use it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` API is not public. To apply one or more high quality effects to an image or a set of images, you can use Direct2D.

Here are some helpful links for you get started:

[How to load an image into Direct2D effects using the FilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/load-a-id2d1image-using-the-filepicker)

[Directional blur effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/directional-blur)

[Custom effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/custom-effects)

And if you still you still want to use `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` API, I would suggest that you raise your voice on [Feedback Hub](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app).

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-radius to make a workaround
(UpdateLayeredWindow is equivalent to WA_TranslucentBackground, SetWindowRgn don' have affect over SetWindowCompositionAttribute blur)

[image: blurry]

Full code:

```
Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {

    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 100;
    border: 8px solid #cdced4;  
    
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: red;
}
"""

import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from BlurWindow.blurWindow import GlobalBlur

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        
        self.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.resize(488, 388)
        GlobalBlur(self.winId(),Acrylic=True,hexColor='#FFFFFF20') 
        
        self.Borders() #the real MainWindow

    def Borders(self):
        window = QMainWindow(self)
        window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        window.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        window.resize(500, 400)
        
        self.widget = QWidget(window)
        window.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            'X', self,clicked=exit, objectName='closeButton'))
        self.layout.addWidget(QLabel("<h2 style='color:blue;'>Blurry</h2>"))
        
        window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

UpdateLayeredWindow alpha example: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1544

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried your code, but found that it didn't really realize the round border of acrylic window